# is it possible to send a folder with email-ext or a dynamic report?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I'm trying to send an email notification with gradle report, If I attached only the index.html, I got the report like the image attached:

[image]

> I think it depends from the folders with which the report is related,
>   I would like to send the report as:

[image]

Any ideas how can I do this? Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using Html in the Content Type in your email section, in addition to this, you can display the html content in email body which will also display it in html format.

Please note that file path is relative to the workspace, if file resides in the root of your workspace, filename alone in the path will work, if it resides in a different location try something like this:

```
${FILE,path="target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html"}
```